# Wordpress wp.newPost not able to Add Tags with XMLRPC

Tags: php, wordpress

I've read the similar questions but no joy. I want to add tags when creating a new post using XMLRPC Api.

I am able to send all other parameters perfectly, but tags will not add. Thank you.

```
$params = array('post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish', 
            'post_title' => 'I like coffee',
            'post_content' => 'some more content here',
            'post_name' => 'complete name',
            'post_category' => array('2', '1'),
            'tags_input' => array('lemon', 'pear') 
            );
```

SOLUTION: THIS WORKS

```
 $params = array('post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish', 
            'post_title' => 'I like coffee',
            'post_content' => 'some more content here',
            'post_name' => 'complete name',
            'post_category' => array('2', '1'),
            'terms' => array(   'category' => array('1', '2'),
                                'post_tag' => array('4', '3')
                            )
            );
```

Comment: FYI, I've also tried 'tags_input' => 'lemon, pear'.

Comment: Solution added, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $params = array('post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'post_title' => 'I like coffee',
        'post_content' => 'some more content here',
        'post_name' => 'complete name',
        'post_category' => array('2', '1'),
        'terms' => array(   'category' => array('1', '2'),
                            'post_tag' => array('4', '3')
                        )
        );
```

Comment: This is identical to the solution posted 1.5 years ago in the answer. What's the point?